# Añadir un listener a un Jslider con label JAVA

Tags: java, poo, listener

me gustaría añadir un listener a este JSlider para que me diga que nota músical estoy selecciondo, el código del JSlider es el siguiente.

Pues me gustaría que la salida fuese: "Nota musical elegida DO" por ejemplo.

```
        // Jslider

    notasdemusica = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
    notasdemusica.setBounds(50, 50, 275, 40);
    notasdemusica.setPaintLabels(true);
    notasdemusica.setPaintTicks(true);
    notasdemusica.setMajorTickSpacing(15);
    notasdemusica.setMinorTickSpacing(15);

    Dictionary<Integer, Component> labelnotas = new Hashtable<Integer, Component>();
    labelnotas.put(0, new JLabel("DO"));
    labelnotas.put(15, new JLabel("RE"));
    labelnotas.put(30, new JLabel("MI"));
    labelnotas.put(45, new JLabel("FA"));
    labelnotas.put(60, new JLabel("SOL"));
    labelnotas.put(75, new JLabel("LA"));
    labelnotas.put(90, new JLabel("SI"));

    notasdemusica.setLabelTable(labelnotas);

    contentPane.add(notasdemusica);
```

Comment: Hola ¿cual es tu pregunta? ¿Parte del código no funciona? ¿O estás recibiendo un error? Si solo quieres saber cómo funciona JSlider, puedes probar esto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html

Comment: Quiero que me saque en un Jlabel la posición en la que está el Slider. Por ejemplo si está en “si” que me sale en un label la nota musical está en “si” o si está el slider seleccionado en el “do” que me saque en un label que está en “do”

Comment: Cuando el valor sea entre 1 y 14 ¿qué debería suceder?

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar un `ChangeListener` para lograr esto, este oyente ejecutará alguna acción cada vez que se modifique el valor de JSlider.

Y también necesita un `JLabel` en algún lugar de su panel para que pueda mostrar el valor seleccionado (si entendí su pregunta correctamente)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    
    private final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("##");
    private final JSlider notasdemusica = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
    
    public Window() {
        createWindow();
        createComponents();
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        lbl.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 20);
        
        notasdemusica.setBounds(50, 50, 275, 40);
        notasdemusica.setPaintLabels(true);
        notasdemusica.setPaintTicks(true);
        notasdemusica.setMajorTickSpacing(15);
        notasdemusica.setMinorTickSpacing(15);

        Dictionary<Integer, Component> labelnotas = new Hashtable<Integer, Component>();
        labelnotas.put(0, new JLabel("DO"));
        labelnotas.put(15, new JLabel("RE"));
        labelnotas.put(30, new JLabel("MI"));
        labelnotas.put(45, new JLabel("FA"));
        labelnotas.put(60, new JLabel("SOL"));
        labelnotas.put(75, new JLabel("LA"));
        labelnotas.put(90, new JLabel("SI"));

        notasdemusica.setLabelTable(labelnotas);
        
        notasdemusica.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                int value = ((JSlider)e.getSource()).getValue();
                if (value < 10) {
                    lbl.setText("DO");
                } else if (value < 20) {
                    lbl.setText("RE");
                } else if (value < 35) {
                    lbl.setText("MI");
                }
                //más else if aquí hasta que termines
            }
        });

        add(notasdemusica);
        add(lbl);
        
    }
    
    private void createWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window w = new Window();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```